# Support for Websockets on Android

Tags: websocket, socket.io, trigger.io

I'm about to start a project for a client that has lots of data that needs to be real-time.

There are two mobile apps that I will be building with trigger.io, as well as a web UI, and all of these need to stay in sync.

I plan to use socket.io's WebSocket implementation with my Node.js backend for the webapp & mobile apps. This will work great on iOS and modern web browsers.

However, Android's webview does not support websockets at all.  And it would simply destroy the mobile app user's data plan if socket.io used its long-polling fallback on Android.

I was wondering: is there any possibility of an implementation of Java WebSockets for trigger.io Android, then exposing that to the WebView?  There is a [simple implementation](https://github.com/mkuklis/phonegap-websocket) for phonegap

I suppose I could write a trigger.io plugin for it - but I want to be sure before I jump in to this project if this is feasible / not too hard to write a plugin for.

I used trigger.io long ago, but not since all the fanciness came out like native plugins.

Comment: I'm using Pusher's JS API in a trigger.io app. It works great on iOS and Android (back to 2.3).

Have you considered something like Meteor or Derby?

Comment: I know it will work, but I'm wondering about long polling's effect on the user's data plan.

Comment: @AndyJoslin, what did you end up doing? Thanks!

Comment: I used Firebase, it worked great.

Answer (score 4):

If using an HTTP fallback solution isn't an option (I'd do some calculations to determine if a streaming or long-polling solution would really "destroy the mobile users's data plan") then the best solution to add WebSocket support would probably be a trigger.io plugin.

At Pusher we used a Java wrapper in PhoneGap in order to get our JavaScript library to work. However we've since added HTTP fallback so I wouldn't recommend anybody use this now. The project is here:
https://github.com/pusher/pusher-phonegap-android

The problem with the Java wrapper here (we use [websocket-android-phonegap](https://github.com/anismiles/websocket-android-phonegap)) is that it doesn't support SSL connections (if I remember correctly) and it hasn't been updated for a long time.

With that in mind when we created the [Pusher Java library](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-java-client) (which supports Android) we used the WebSocket client in [Java-WebSocket](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket) because it's being actively developed and supports SSL connections. I'd recommend it.

I'd be interested to hear about the support that https://github.com/mkuklis/phonegap-websocket provides.

Comment: You are right, I took a guess with the long polling being 'super evil' - I'll look into it more!
And thanks for the pusher java library link, I'll take a look at it.

Comment: HTTP streaming will be more efficient as the streaming connection is persisted and doesn't open/close as the connection does with long-polling.

Comment: cool! I looked it up ... didn't even know how that stuff worked, haha. I thought long polling was "send an HTTP request every X seconds to check server status' - but it's a lot different.

Comment: @AndyJoslin common misconception. FYI I've started a mini-guide here: http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-web-technologies-guide/realtime-web-technology-transport-mechanisms

Comment: Web sockets aren't always supported on mobile networks either! I found that some use proxies using http 1.0 which remove some of the necessary headers

Comment: hi legetter, i have done recently a webapp that uses the websocket, i'have try to use the phonegap websocket module, but for some reason it didn't work, i have use the cordova install plugin script and builded the app, i miss something to do? did i have to put a link to the src in html page or somethin else?